# "Exception in thread "main" java.util.MissingFormatArgumentException: Format specifier '%.4f'"

Tags: java

I'm looking to print the surface area and volume in 4 decimal places using %.4f. I have no clue what the error in the title means. Here is the source code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class VolumeAndSurfaceArea {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Radius is abbrebriated to "r"
        double r = sc.nextDouble();
        double SA = 4.0 * 3.14 * r * r;
        double V = 4/3 * 3.14 * r * r * r;
        double helper_SA = SA;
        System.out.printf("The Surface Area is: %.4f" + SA);
        System.out.printf("The Volume is: %.4f" + V);
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than concatenating the `double` values to the end of your `String` messages, add them to the argument list like so:

```java
System.out.printf("The Surface Area is: %.4f", SA);
System.out.printf("The Volume is: %.4f", V);
```